# Como colocar negrillas o un vinculo en un JSON en flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Necesito saber como se puede colocar las letras en negrilla y un vinculo dentro de un info de un JSON por ejemplo.

```
{
"info":"texto cualquiera (texto en negrilla): www.info.com"
}
```

Este ejemplo es algo relativo de lo que necesito y la salida seria de la siguente forma:

texto cualquiera (**texto en negrilla**): [www.info.com](https://www.info.com)

Les agradesco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que esto podría ser una `String` de `json` con una gran cantidad de datos, querrá decodificar el `json` y luego iterar sobre el mapa de datos. Luego dividiría los datos para cada key en el mapa.

```
import 'dart:convert';

String jsonString = '{"info":"texto cualquiera (texto en negrilla): www.info.com"}';
Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
for (String key in jsonMap.keys){
  List data = jsonMap[key].split('): ');
  String vinculo  = data[1];
  String textoNegrilla = data[0].split('(')[1];
}
```

Comment: Es un etxto muy largo, son como 4 páginas de texto, no creo que me funcione si tengo que buscar uno por uno, seria mucho codigo spaguetti.

Comment: Yo creería que la respuesta de @Scott es válida, porque la verdad yo no he visto que se pueda enviar datos en negrita en un json, pero al obtener estos datos ahí si tu ya podrías manipular estos datos

Comment: Mil gracias, tienes razon, tampoco he visto voy a probar una cosa y vuelvo a escribir.

Comment: Correcto, intenta obtener estos datos y ahí mostrarlos en la UI con las propiedades que le quieras dar

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar las negrillas en Flutter me toco hacer un BcRichtext, para poder utilizar (*) simple, cambie el BcText que es por defecto.

```
BcRichText(
              overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
              fontSize: 14,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              text: info,
              key: const Key('text'),
            ),
```

Luego de usar eso en mi info que dejé arriba, solo fue colocar * para que saliera el etxto en negrilla.

```
{
"info":"texto cualquiera *texto en negrilla:* www.info.com"
}
```

texto cualquiera **texto en negrilla:** [www.info.com](https://info.com)

pero aun estoy buscando la manera de hacerlo con un link.